# Filter multiple pokemons of PokeApi

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I make a request to **'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}'** to obtain the information of a specific pokemon, the problem is that the name must be the same otherwise it returns undefined, I need to filter many pokemons, for example: if I search for char it should return charmeleon and charizard, because they both have 'char'. How can I filter a lot of pokemons?

```js
const params = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}

const searchPokemon = async name => {
  const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, params);
    const result = await response.json();
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: If the API will only return results for exact matches, then there isn't really a good way to do this. You would end up having to spam a bunch of requests to see which ones are valid. I would suggest looking through the API documentation more to see if they offer a search feature or maybe a way to query the list of all pokemon names. If you can get a list of all the valid names, then you can search against that list instead of searching against the API.

Comment: You should read the API documentation and ask questions to API tech support team, I didn't have time to look at the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of all possible pokemon names, you can make a request to `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100000` (where 100000 is larger than the number of pokemon that exist. There appear to be only 1118 pokemon as of now.)

The result looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    name:"bulbasaur",
    url:"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"
  },
  {
    name:"ivysaur",
    url:"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"
  },
  {
    name:"venusaur",
    url:"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/"
  },
  ...
]
```

Then you can filter out that list based on the names you are looking for. After you find the name you want, you can use the corresponding URL to get more information.

Comment: ok I understand, but returning more than 1000 objects can't have a performance problem? . Or it will just delay the api response

Comment: Well, the number of Pokémon won’t change very often, so you can query the full list once and then save the result for future lookups. You could maybe re-update the full list weekly, daily, hourly, whatever. Also I don’t think the full list query even takes that long anyway. But caching it would certainly help your end-to-end search time because that’s one less HTTP request to make.

Comment: thanks, i checked on my own, and there really is no performance problem, it just takes a little time if you have low internet speed